# Height of text not correct in fixed-height table

Tags: tables, fontsize

I am making a puzzle that involves putting the letters of nine-letter words in 3x3 boxes, and have written the following code to get started (MWE).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\letters}[9]{\resizebox{1.75em}{!}{\begin{tabular}{ccc} #1 & #2 & #3 \\ #4 & #5 & #6 \\ #7 & #8 & #9 \end{tabular}}}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\letters{V}{I}{T}{R}{I}{O}{L}{I}{C}
\letters{P}{E}{R}{I}{S}{C}{O}{P}{E}
\letters{N}{U}{M}{E}{R}{A}{T}{O}{R}
\letters{A}{C}{T}{I}{V}{A}{T}{E}{D}
\letters{G}{L}{A}{S}{S}{W}{A}{R}{E}
\letters{I}{T}{E}{R}{A}{T}{I}{O}{N}
\letters{W}{H}{O}{O}{S}{H}{I}{N}{G}
\end{document}
```

However, as seen in this screenshot, it appears that the cells of the table are not all the correct size, with `VITRIOLIC` being larger than `PERISCOPE`, `ACTIVATED`, and `ITERATION`, all of which are larger than `NUMERATOR`, `GLASSWARE`, and `WHOOSHING`.

[image]

How do I make all of the letters the same height?

Answer (score 2):

By choosing a TABstack instead of a `tabular`, I can make column widths uniform across a word.  I'm not sure if this is what you need, but I choose to perform the `\resizebox` across the complete row and not each `\letters` macro.

The macro `\setstacktabulargap{<length>}` may be used to set the gap between letters within thetabstack, and I have selected a 1em gap between adjacent letter groups.  In the first two rows, the only change is the size of the `\setstacktabulargap`.

Note that while the OP's syntax, `\letters{V}{I}{T}{R}{I}{O}{L}{I}{C}`, will still work with this implementation, the invocation can be significantly simplified with no changes to the code: `\letters VITRIOLIC`.

I wrap it all in a macro `\setrow[<width>]{}` into which the various letter invocations are made.

At the request of the OP to make it compatible with `tabular`, I EDITED the answer to do several things:

1. I added an optional argument to `\setrow` to specify the desired group width;
2. I change the stack end-of-line delimiting character from `\\` to `\cr`, so that `tabular` did not get confused (thus, the `\letters` definition needed revision to reflect this).
3. I changed the vertical stacking gap [baselineskip] from the default `\baselinekip` to `\normalbaselineskip`, since the latter is not reset within a `tabular` environment; and
4. I changed the `\tabularLongstack` to a `\tabularCenterstack`, so that the stack would be centered around the baseline, rather than sitting upon it.

Here is the MWE (note: I got rid of `\Huge` at the opening of the document):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\fixTABwidth{T}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\setstackgap{L}{\normalbaselineskip}
\setstacktabulargap{.5em}
\newcommand{\letters}[9]{\tabularCenterstack{ccc}{#1&#2&#3\cr#4&#5&#6\cr#7&#8&#9}\hspace{1em}}
\newcommand\setrow[2][\textwidth]{\noindent\resizebox{#1}{!}{#2\hspace{-1em}}}
\begin{document}
\setrow{%
\letters VITRIOLIC
\letters PERISCOPE
\letters NUMERATOR
\letters ACTIVATED
\letters GLASSWARE
\letters ITERATION
\letters WHOOSHING}

\bigskip

\setstacktabulargap{.1em}
\setrow{%
\letters VITRIOLIC
\letters PERISCOPE
\letters NUMERATOR
\letters ACTIVATED
\letters GLASSWARE
\letters ITERATION
\letters WHOOSHING}

\bigskip

\setrow{%
\letters VITRIOLIC
\letters PERISCOPE
\letters NUMERATOR
\letters ACTIVATED
\letters GLASSWARE}

\lipsum[1]

{\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Game Number & Game\\
\hline
1 & \setrow[.5\textwidth]{%
\letters VITRIOLIC
\letters PERISCOPE
\letters NUMERATOR
\letters ACTIVATED
\letters GLASSWARE
}\\
\hline
2 & \setrow[.5\textwidth]{%
\letters NUMERATOR
\letters ACTIVATED
\letters GLASSWARE
\letters ITERATION
\letters WHOOSHING}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is nice. I'm trying to incorporate this into a table, but am having difficulties. Could you assist me with that?

Comment: @Eridan Please see revision.

Answer (score 1):

You can use packages `stringstrings` and `tikz`, the first one to extract the letters of the word and the second one to place them uniformly.
I have added an optional argument to the command `\squareword` to have control over the separation between the letters.
By default the separation is 1em.

The result:

[image]

And the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\squareword}[2][1em]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \z in {1,...,9}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\i}{mod(\z-1,3)}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{(\i-\z+1)/3}
        \coordinate (a\z) at (#1*\i,#1*\j);}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,9}{
        \substring[q]{#2}{\y}{\y}
        \node[anchor=base] at (a\y){\thestring};}
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\squareword{VITRIOLIC}
\squareword{PERISCOPE}
\squareword{NUMERATOR}
\squareword{ACTIVATED}
\squareword{GLASSWARE}
\squareword{ITERATION}
\squareword{WHOOSHING}

\Huge
\squareword{VITRIOLIC}
\squareword{PERISCOPE}
\squareword{NUMERATOR}
\squareword{ACTIVATED}
\squareword{GLASSWARE}
\squareword{ITERATION}
\squareword{WHOOSHING}

\normalsize
\squareword[1.5em]{VITRIOLIC}
\squareword[2em]{PERISCOPE}
\squareword[0.8em]{NUMERATOR}
\squareword[0.5em]{ACTIVATED}
\squareword[3mm]{GLASSWARE}
\squareword[4mm]{ITERATION}
\squareword[0.5cm]{WHOOSHING}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Klutzy, but it does the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\letter}[1]{{\fontsize{24}{24}\selectfont #1}}
\newcommand{\letters}[9]{\begin{tabular}{ccc} \letter{#1} & \letter{#2} & \letter{#3} \\ \letter{#4} & \letter{#5} & \letter{#6} \\ \letter{#7} & \letter{#8} & \letter{#9} \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\letters{V}{I}{T}{R}{I}{O}{L}{I}{C}
\letters{P}{E}{R}{I}{S}{C}{O}{P}{E}
\letters{N}{U}{M}{E}{R}{A}{T}{O}{R}
\letters{A}{C}{T}{I}{V}{A}{T}{E}{D}
\letters{G}{L}{A}{S}{S}{W}{A}{R}{E}
\letters{I}{T}{E}{R}{A}{T}{I}{O}{N}
\letters{W}{H}{O}{O}{S}{H}{I}{N}{G}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This makes the tables all coincide with each other, and when the `resizebox` line is added back in, the problem persists.

Comment: Yes, the resizebox IS the problem.  To make things bigger, resize the letters instead of the box containing them.

Comment: Or, alternatively, make all entries of the tabular the same size using one of the phantom commands.

Comment: Adjusting the font size and `baselineskip` (changes to this appear to do nothing) add an excessive amount of vertical and horizontal whitespace in the table. Is there a solution that doesn't do this?

Answer (score 0):

The widths may be different. You should resize to height.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\letters}[9]{%
  \resizebox{!}{1em}{%
    \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    #1 & #2 & #3 \\
    #4 & #5 & #6 \\
    #7 & #8 & #9
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\letters{V}{I}{T}{R}{I}{O}{L}{I}{C}
\letters{P}{E}{R}{I}{S}{C}{O}{P}{E}
\letters{N}{U}{M}{E}{R}{A}{T}{O}{R}
\letters{A}{C}{T}{I}{V}{A}{T}{E}{D}
\letters{G}{L}{A}{S}{S}{W}{A}{R}{E}
\letters{I}{T}{E}{R}{A}{T}{I}{O}{N}
\letters{W}{H}{O}{O}{S}{H}{I}{N}{G}
\end{document}
```

[image]